# how to handle iteratons to list different item each time

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to write a program that finds the number of different items counting the numbers of folders. And the number of each item counting the number of photos inside of each of this folders. 
Once I have that I would like to make a loop that uses a different item for every iteration. For example if I have 3 different items I would like to list the first item from the first type, then the second and so on. Like this:

```
  y=0
    num=[]
    for dir in next(os.walk('.'))[1]:
        for folder in os.listdir(dir):
            if folder.startswith("photos"):
                num.append(0)
                for file in os.listdir(dir+"\\"+folder):
                    if file.endswith(".jpg"):
                        num[y]+=1

                y +=1

for every item since there are no more items (everyone has a diferent number)
    do
        for dir in next(os.walk('.'))[1]:
            for folder in os.listdir(dir):
                if folder.startswith("photos"):
                    num.append(0)
                    for file in os.listdir(dir+"\\"+folder):
                        if file.endswith(".jpg"):
```

What would be the correct way?
I've come with this for now, but not what I want as you can see:

```
y=0
num=[]
for dir in next(os.walk('.'))[1]:
    for folder in os.listdir(dir):
        if folder.startswith("photos"):
            num.append(0)
            for file in os.listdir(dir+"\\"+folder):
                if file.endswith(".jpg"):
                    num[y]+=1

            y +=1
print (num)
print (len(num)) 

for dir in next(os.walk('.'))[1]:
    for folder in os.listdir(dir):
        if folder.startswith("photos"):
            for file in os.listdir(dir+"\\"+folder):
                if file.endswith(".jpg"):
```

this could be and example of the tree directory

```
flowers (would be item 1)
    -photos
            photo1
            photo2
    -otherthing
books (would be item 2)
    -photos
            photo1

otherthing (no item because has no photos folder inside)

oterthing (no item because has no photos folder inside)
    -videos
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you describe more clearly step by step what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice added and example a part from my code. Check now

Comment: Can you add an example of the directory tree and the output desired for that directory?

Comment: @cosmoscalibur done

Comment: @Zaico but if you mix directory tree with comments of the output will not be clear. You need put how is the directory tree and how is the output desired (new block). I don't see where your description is equal to the given example.

Comment: Please include expected output along with your example. If I understand the question correctly, would the expected output for your example be: `["flowers\photos\photo1.jpg","books\photos\photo1.jpg","flowers\photos\photo2.jgp"]`?